# Use LINQ to combine a property in a list of lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary that looks like such: `Dictionary<Search_Requests, List<Tuple<Search_Subjects, SearchData>>>`

In the `SearchData` class, there's a property called `SearchCode`. What I want to do is get an array of every search code that appears in this dictionary. I could do this with a few loops, but I'd really prefer to use LINQ. Unfortunately, I can't wrap my mind around how to do this. I tried

```
RequestDictionary.Select(s => s.Value.Select(z => s.Value.Select(x => x.Item2.SearchCode).ToArray()).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

But that just got me a `string[][][]`, which isn't close to what I wanted. Can I get a push in the right direction?

Comment: Check out `SelectMany()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I just need to change my outer selects into `SelectMany` and it should be good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flatten the results:

```
RequestDictionary
    .SelectMany(s 
        => s.Value.SelectMany(z => s.Value.Select(x => x.Item2.SearchCode))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to combine `.Select()` and `.SelectMany()`:

```
var codes = requestDictionary
               //Extract all List<>s from the dictionary and enumerate them back-to-back:
               .SelectMany(entry => entry.Value)
               //Extract the SearchCode from each list item:
               .Select(tuple => tuple.Item2.SearchCode)
               .ToArray();
```